# check a string array from a list contains a string from another list or vice versa

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a easy way to do this using linq?

I want to check and return true or false, whether any string from list1 contains a string from array1. In the below example that would be string2value and i would want to return true.

Also similarly i want to check whether any array1 would contain a string from list1. That would be string1blah and so that would return true as well. Thanks!

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>{"string1","string2value"};

string[] array1 = new string[2] {"string1blah","string2"};
```

I have a couple of versions, but it does not work all the time.

```
array1.ToList().Any(a=>list1.Contains(a))
list1.Any(l=>array1.ToList().Contains(l))
```

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking? Do you want to return true if list1 contains any items from array1? Or do you want to return all the items in array1 which are contained in list1?

Comment: I just want to return true at the moment.

Comment: Can you not do an `Intersect().Any()`?

Comment: @code4life OP is asking for string.Contains, not equals.

Comment: Argh. I just noticed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var result= list1.Where(s=>array1.Any(s1=>s.Contains(s1)));
```

Per each string in the `list1`, you see if there is an element in `array1` that is contained in `s` string.

Comment: you have to mention that just the OP should the same  for the other array

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel you are right, but I thought cableload can deduce that part :). Anyway thanks for the clarification

Comment: Thanks @octavioccl This works. I tried both ways and was able to get the match i want.

Answer (score 1):

The way your question is worded it is hard to understand what you want.

If you want all the strings in one list which are substrings of an element in the other list, then this should work:

```
var substrings = myList.Where(bigstring => myArray.Any(substring => bigstring.Contains(substring)));
```

If you just want to know whether such an element exists, then do this:

```
bool myCondition = myList.Any(bigstring => myArray.Any(substring => bigstring.Contains(substring)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting pretty linq, you can do:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var list1 = new List<string> { "string1", "string2value" };
        var array1 = new string[] { "string1blah", "string2" };

        var result = from sl in list1
                     from sa in array1
                     where sl.Contains(sa) || sa.Contains(sl)
                     select new { sl, sa };

        foreach (var x in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
```

Which gives nice output

```
{ sl = string1, sa = string1blah }
{ sl = string2value, sa = string2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use linq query expressions if you want.

Give this code:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "string1", "string2value" };
string[] array1 = new string[2] { "string1blah", "string2" };
```

> I want to check and return true or false, whether any string from list1 contains a string from array1. In the below example that would be string2value and i would want to return true.

You can do it like this:

```
var result = from l1 in list1
             from a1 in array1
             where l1.Contains(a1)
             select l1; // Or select true if you want to just return true
```

> Also similarly i want to check whether any array1 would contain a string from list1. That would be string1blah and so that would return true as well. Thanks!

You can modify the above to achieve it like this:

```
var result = from l1 in list1
             from a1 in array1
             where a1.Contains(l1)
             select a1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To return true or false (as you've mentioned in the OP Comments), you would modify the call to count the items contained, and if greater than 0, return true.

**EDIT** Thanks Dax Fohl

```
var list1 = new List<string> {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"};
var array1 = new string[] {"Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6"};

var result = list1.Any(s => array1.Any(s.Contains));
```

Comment: `Count .. > 0` can be reduced to `Any`